# Make gif spinning concentric circles in different directions

Tags: svg, gif, gimp, inkscape

I have the following image saved as SVG:
[Concentric circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jssBr.png)

As you can see, the image contains 3 concentric circles, and I was wondering how can I create a gif with the 3 circles spinning. The complicated part is that I need the middle circle to spin in a different direction than the inner and outter circles. I usually work with GIMP and Inkscape, and I'm not sure if it's possible to use any of them to do that. Searched a lot but withou success.

Do you know how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Gimp you can use the [`ofn-path-marquee` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/);

[image]

You just create circle path(s) and let it do the rest, it is basically a dash pattern with a varying offset. The script does the necessary tweaks to make sure there is an integer number of dashes, all the same length.

See [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-path-marquee) for some other examples.